Question on logarithms related to expressing $10^{16}$ in terms of a given constant $m$
The question is

If the value of $\log(k-m) = k^2$ and $\log(k-m)^9 = 24k-16$, prove that the value of $10^{16}$ in terms of $m$ is $\left(\frac 43 - m\right)^9$.

My Attempt:
I found out that if we try to solve the second equation by using the first equation we get a quadratic equation in terms of $k$. Since $\log m^n$ = $n \log m$
so $\log(k-m)^9 = 9 \log(k-m)$ and then we can put the value of $\log(k-m)$ which we already know. After solving the quadratic equation we get two identical roots ie $\frac 43$. But I don't know how to continue the question I have tried a lot of ways but nothing seems to work. It seems that the things that are given in the questions and the thing which we need to find are not related. can anyone tell me how can I further move on with this question what should I do next?

I suppose that $\log$ here means $\log_{10}$. Then you know that$$\log_{10}\left(\left(\frac 43-m\right)^9\right)=24\times\frac43-16=16.$$Therefore,$$\left(\frac 43-m\right)^9=10^{16}.$$

Ah, how could I overlook that  It's  only the definition of log.
